# Terraform - is there any way to define an object with multiple potential types?

Tags: variables, types, terraform

Looking for ideas if this is possible. (I seem to recall posts elsewhere that it isn't directly available, but having difficulty finding them to reference... sorry in advance.)

My team is attempting to code all of our org's currently-deployed Azure policies/initiatives into Terraform. In particular, there may be different parameters for the initiatives between different environments (sandbox/dev/test/prod), so the last thing I'm trying to code is the parameter definitions and parameter values into variables (in one .tfvars files per environment) instead of in code (in main.tf each for policyset definition and assignment). This way we can have one code-base, even if there are different parameters needed per environment.

Here's the problem... the type of the defaultValue attribute of the parameter definitions is not consistent across all the parameters.

Sample attempt at variable definition:

```
variable "parameters_apim_definitions" {
  type = map(object({
    type = string
    metadata = map(string)
    allowedValues = list(string0
    defaultValue = any
  }))
  description = "Definitions of parameters for the sql_governance policyset."
}
```

For example, in different parameters, defaultValue might be a string (say, "Management"), a number (365), or a boolean (true), or even an array ([ "Developer", "Premium" ]).

Trying this, though, I get the following error:

│ Error: Incorrect variable type
│
│ on variables.tf line 34:
│ 34: variable "parameters_apim_definitions" {
│
│ The resolved value of variable "parameters_apim_definitions" is not appropriate: cannot find a common base type for
│ all elements.

Unfortunately, it looks like, according to https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/type-constraints#dynamic-types-the-any-constraint, that "any" can translate into any type, but they all need to be the SAME type.

Any ideas? I've got one (multiple default definitions, one for each possible type, with try clauses to pick the non-null one), but... what ugly code that will take.

Comment: The `any` type means that the input value can be "any" one type for a given config execution. Unfortunately, it does mean the input can be "any" value for a given config execution. I think maybe Martin Atkins wrote an answer at one point for a workaround for this use case, but I cannot recall where it is on SO. It would definitely require 0.13 or newer since `any` was prone to segmentation faults in 0.12.

Comment: Yeah, IIRC, the references I saw were to a feature request to support more-dynamic objects in lists. They were 1-2 years old, so I hoped that perhaps there had been some progress.

I don't think the version is a problem, although I would need to double-check to be certain.

Comment: Semi-obvious typo that the second "does" should be "does not". SO not supporting comment editing etc.